# Performing Set calculations in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, union, intersection, set-theory

I have 2 arrays lets say:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5] and B = [1,2,3,6,7]
```

and I'd like to perform the following 'set calculations':

```
C = (A ∩ B)
D = A - (A ∩ B)
E = B - (A ∩ B)
```

Essentially:

```
C = [1,2,3]
D = [4,5]
E = [6,7]
```

Is there a smart way to do this or am I going to have to cross check each array member with loops and ifs? I cannot use an external library (like math.js or w/e).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you cannot use an external library, it seems you are going to have to depend on lots of raw for-loops or writing a small library of your own. Either way, you'll be using for-loops. Hopefully, this isn't homework.

Comment: No this isn't homework it is work related and I do not want to add a whole external library into our SVN project just for 3 lines of code. I can think of ways to get the result I want I just thought of asking here for a more elegant solution. Also I haven't had the need to use set theory with arrays before so I thought it would be a good idea to learn some stuff here for later use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can at least *hide* the loops for you:

```js
A = [1,2,3,4,5];
B = [1,2,3,6,7];

C = intersection(A, B);
D = arrayDiff(A, C);
E = arrayDiff(B, C);

console.log(JSON.stringify(C));
console.log(JSON.stringify(D));
console.log(JSON.stringify(E));

function intersection(a, b) {
  return a.filter( 
    function(el) {
      return b.indexOf(el) >= 0;
    }
  );
}

function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  return a.filter( 
    function(el) {
      return b.indexOf(el) < 0;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: It's times like these that I appreciate being proved wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As of ES6, Javascript has an [inbuilt set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which offers neat ways to do the above operations.

```js
var intersection = (setA, setB) => new Set([...setA].filter(x => setB.has(x)));

var difference = (setA, setB) => new Set([...setA].filter(x => !setB.has(x)));

A = new Set([1,2,3,4,5]);
B = new Set([1,2,3,6,7]);

// A ∩ B = ([1,2,3])
console.log(intersection(A, B));

// A \ B = ([4,5])
console.log(difference(A, B));

// B \ A = ([6,7])
console.log(difference(B, A));
```

Comment: this is not valid JavaScript